# Web Service Authorization header returning odd characters in service

Tags: c#, .net, http, wcf, service

I have written a WPF application that sends a POST WebHTTPRequest to a WCF service. The service required windows credentials to perform operations on the server. When the service receives the HTTP request, it is unable to parse the Authorization header.

The POST request begins like this.

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
req.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
req.Accept = "application/json";
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", Base64Encode(Details.username + ":" + Details.password + ":" + Details.domain));
req.Method = "POST";
byte[] reqBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body.ToString());
```

And is received on the service like this

```
IncomingWebRequestContext request = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;
WebHeaderCollection headers = request.Headers;

if (headers["Authorization"] != null)
{
    cred = headers["Authorization"];
} else
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(result);
    return;
}
```

I print the "cred" variable to a log file and what I get begins something like this "敎潧楴瑡⁥䥙䝉䅺䝙" which, quite clearly, is wrong. Can anybody tell me why I'm getting this output as opposed to the input consisting of the English characters I sent the request with?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you encoded a UTF-8 encoded string into Base64.
You specified that the charset type for your JSON file is UTF-8 here:

```
req.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
```

So when you tried to encode your Authentication into Base64 it would have ruined your string.

```
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", Base64Encode(Details.username + ":" + Details.password + ":" + Details.domain));
```

Try a different way of encoding the string

Comment: Yeah, this didn't work, I'm still receiving a string that begins "敎潧楴瑡⁥" in the log file.